# Magento 2 Google language translate script not working

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs, magento2.4.6

**The script was functional on our Magento 2 website until last week. However, for the past four days, we've been encountering JavaScript and Knockout.js errors in the console when this script is active. Upon its removal, everything functions properly. We've also tested this on a fresh Magento 2 installation and experienced conflicts. Surprisingly, the script operates without issues on a standard static website. Could anyone assist in resolving this conflict?**

***Error SS: https://i.imgur.com/JNihVVD.png***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({
            pageLanguage: 'en',
        }, 'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script
```

> 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the Magento 2 core require.js file and add the following snippet inside the define function:

```
// Restrict pako library in google translate module from loading
    if(typeof name !== 'string' && isFunction(deps) && deps.toString().includes('pako')){
        return;
    }
```

So, that the require.js will change from:
[image: This is what define function looks by default]

to:
[image: After adding the above line it will look like this. Notice the code in the red highlighted box]

Comment: how can i override this file into my custom module?

Comment: You can copy the require.js from magento vendor and override it in your theme in the following path:
`app/design/frontend/<Your theme vendor>/<your theme name>/web/requirejs/require.js`
and then add the changes that I shared above.

Comment: How to override in my custom module, not in theme.

Answer (score 0):

> You have an anonymous define ("modules that call define() with no string ID") in its own script tag (I assume actually they mean anywhere in global scope)

> The issue I ran into was that most of the beginner examples use "anonymous defines" when you should be using a "string id".

**anonymous defines**

```
define(function() {
        return { helloWorld: function() { console.log('hello world!') } };
 })
    
  
define(function() {
        return { helloWorld2: function() { console.log('hello world again!') } };
 })
```

**create googleTranslateElementInit function like this**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            define(function() {
                return { googleTranslateElementInit: function() {
                    new google.translate.TranslateElement(
                        {
                            pageLanguage: 'en',
                            includedLanguages: '<?php echo strtolower($block->getCountry()); ?>',
                            layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.HORIZONTAL
                        },'google_translate_element'); } };
            })
    </script>
```

Comment: Patelthanks for the reply I am using your solution but i facing an error: https://i.imgur.com/XLJPkjt.png

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-language">
<label for="select-language"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Language')) ?> 
</label>

 <!-- Google Element Translator Styling-->
    <style>
        .goog-te-combo{width: px !important;}
        .goog-te-balloon-frame{display: none !important;}
        font{background: transparent !important;}
        a font:hover{ color:  !important;}
        #google_translate_element{height: 26px !important;overflow: hidden !important;}
        .goog-te-banner-frame{display: none !important;}
        body{top: 0px !important;}
    </style> 

  <!-- Google Element Translator -->
<div id="google_language_drop">
    <div id="google_translate_element" class="-blank"></div>
        <script>
            function googleTranslateElementInit() {
                new google.translate.TranslateElement({
                    includedLanguages: 'en,it,es,fr,zh-CN',
                    //pageLanguage: '<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('en')) ?>',
                    gaTrack: true,
                    gaId: 'UA-12345678-1'
                }, 'google_translate_element');
            }
        </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: still i facing same issue.